# CLOSURE : retrieve a variable given with the outer function

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, closures

Is it possible to retrieve a variable, which is given with the outer function?

Python :

```py
def html_tag(tag):
    print(" : <{t}>".format(t=tag))
    def wrap_text(msg):
        print("<{t}>{m}<{t}>".format(t=tag, m=msg))

    return wrap_text


print_h1 = html_tag("h1")
print_div = html_tag("div")
print_span = html_tag("span")
print_h1("h1 - test met h1")
print_div("div - mouse button")
print_span("span - tekst met tag")
```

In my case I would like to see/retrieve the variable `tag` in the different functions.

[image: link to the excuted python code]

```py
print ( "help(print_h1)   : ", help(print_h1), "")
print ( "dir(print_h1)    : ", dir(print_h1), "")
print ( "print_h1.__dir__ : ", (print_h1.__dir__), "")
#print (print_h1.tag, "")
print ( "print_h1         : ",print_h1.__closure__, "\n")
print ( "print_h1         : ",print_h1, "\n")
```

returns :

```py
Help on function wrap_text in module __main__:

wrap_text(msg)

help(print_h1)   :  None 
dir(print_h1)    :  ['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__'] 
print_h1.__dir__ :  <built-in method __dir__ of function object at 0x7f2f42fbdb90> 
print_h1         :  (<cell at 0x7f2f42f73310: str object at 0x7f2f51f066b0>,) 

print_h1         :  <function html_tag.<locals>.wrap_text at 0x7f2f42fbdb90>
```

---

**SO WHEN I TRY IT LIKE THIS**
it is not in the dictionary of the `.__dir__` ...

```py
print (print_h1.tag)
```

**ERROR**

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-71ea208bcc8c> in <module>()
----> 1 print (print_h1.tag)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

---

***EDIT - I would like to retrieve the `tag` variable***

```py
print_h1.__closure__:  (<cell at 0x7f2f42f73310: str object at 0x7f2f51f066b0>,)
```

***address memory location*** : `x` - is manual retrieved from previous command

```py
import ctypes

x=0x7f2f51f066b0
# display memory address
print("Memory address - ", x)
  
# get the value through memory address
a = ctypes.cast(x, ctypes.py_object).value
  
# display
print("Value - ", a)
```

returns :

```py
Memory address -  139841214899888
Value -  h1
```

Comment: `print_h1.tag` is error because `tag` is assumed to be  an attribute (that you haven' defined) but only have `tag` as  parameter

Comment: functions are first class citizen and also support attributes (!= parameters)

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, the decorator does not contain any variable definition... what do you except to retrieve? Could add an expected output? `html_tag` works properly

Comment: @cards it is defined ... but I don't know how to retrieve it, with `print_h1.__closure__` I'm able to retrieve the memory location. But there is hopefully a better and easier way ... then my workaround.

Correct me if I missunderstand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__closure__` is an (read-only) attribute of a user-defined function object:
it is tuple (or None) of `cell`s that contain bindings for the function’s free variables.

A `cell` object has the (read & write) attribute `cell_contents`. This can be used to get/set the value of the cell.

Note `cell` types can be accessed through [`types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#module-types) module

---

`code` objects are **an** internal type used by the interpreter and accessible by the user.

`co_freevars` is a tuple containing the names of free variable

---

Here an example on how to get the value of the function's parameter and its identifier:

```
# html_tag: from the question

print_h1 = html_tag('h1')

# identifier of the parameter - with code obj
print(print_h1.__code__.co_freevars[0])
#tag

# value of the function's parameter - read
print(print_h1.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
#h1

# value of the function's parameter - write
print_h1.__closure__[0].cell_contents = 'h19'
print_h1('a')
#<h19>a<h19>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... 
The whole idea is to give to get the name of a variable which is passed in function as argument.
Normally I should manage it with this.

Only to figure it out when using more then one argument.

Comment: @kris for more robust stuffs I suggest to give a look to [`ìnspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) :)